# Regex to match numbers 0-99.999

Tags: regex

I need a regex that that matches numbers between 0 and 99.999 (99,999 is also valid).

Valid examples:

```
1,1
99.9
12.876
1,777
```

Invalid examples:

```
9837,83
-12,24
11.1112
```

Comment: I don't understand your requirement. You say it should start with 0 and end with 99.999 or 99,999? But your examples do not show this. Can you make your examples clearer by placing on separate lines please.

Comment: Also, what development environment are you working in?

Comment: @ElRonnoco: I can almost see "numbers between 0-99.999" (and using the [decimal comma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark#Countries_using_Arabic_numerals_with_decimal_comma) ).

Comment: Can there be leading zeroes (`02,345`)? Can the zero be dropped (`.99`)? Can there be a decimal point without following digits (`12.`)?

Comment: I think you're using regex for the wrong reasons,  this is a numeric validation requirement not a text parsing requirement.  Can you not convert to numeric and check the range >= 0 and < 100 ?  If that is what you trying to do of course..

Comment: why `1,1` is valid and `9837,83` is invalid ? Explain.....

Comment: To clarify this post, I believe the OP requires a test that a number is between 0 and 99.999 inclusive with no more that 3dps of precision and using either comma or decimal point separation. I don't like this as what if people enter 1,999 meaning 1 thousand 9 hundred and 99 and not 1.999?

Comment: @infinite - because in some "cultures" a comma is used as a decimal separator. 9837,83 -> 9837.83 which is > 99.999.

Answer (score 5):

```
^\d{1,2}(?:[.,]\d{1,3})?$
```

should do.

**Explanation:**

```
^         # anchor the match at the start of the string
\d{1,2}   # match one or two digits
(?:       # optionally match the following group:
 [.,]     # a . or ,
 \d{1,3}  # 1-3 digits
)?        # end of optional group
$         # anchor the match the end of the string
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are wanting to check a number is within a certain range you should not use Regex, it is too far removed from the logic of what you are doing and hard to debug. I would first replace commas with decimal points. Then check range.

eg (Javascript)

```
function isValid(inputString)
{
   var number=parseFloat(inputString.replace(',','.'));
   return (number>=0 && number <=99.999);
}
```

**Updated Answer**

The above solution does not account for the OP's requirement to have no more than 3 decimal places of precision.

```
function isValid(inputString){
   var number=parseFloat(inputString.replace(',','.'));
   validPrecision = true;
   if (inputString.split('.')[1]) {
       validPrecision=inputString.split('.')[1].length<=3;}
   return (number>=0 && number <=99.999 && validPrecision);
};
```

Comment: and as a plus, it will take into account the locales for decimal and thousands separators

Comment: Please leave comments when downvoting! :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Will this work ?

```
[0-9]{1,2}[.,][0-9]{1,3}
```

this matches stuff similar to this:

- `0.0` /  `01,1`
- `99,999` / `09.009`

but not stuff like this:

- `.0` / `,1` / `1` / `01`
- `099,999` / `09.0090`

hope it helps.

Comment: if you mean stuff la 10 or 25 then it's by design. I never saw the requester wanting to match that. I do say that in the post :)

Answer (score 1):

The following will work:

```
^\d{1,2}((,|.)\d{1,3})?$
```